# How to change the font family of SwitchCompat?

Tags: android, xml, switchcompat

I've noticed that the SwitchCompat's **font** does not seem to change with what I've set in the **fontFamily** field. I've also tried using **styles** with custom fontFamily (*which works on TextViews*) and even the **switchTextAppearance** field. It does apply on the preview (*I know the preview is not really accurate*) but not when I tried running it on my test device.

Here's my SwitchCompat:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            style="@style/MyStyle.Body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/my_font_family"
            android:text="Enable"
            app:switchTextAppearance="@style/MyStyle.Body"/>
```

and here's my style:

```
<style name="MyStyle.Body" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font_family</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_primary_text</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, I only really want to change it's font

---

**EDIT**

I've changed my style to this

```
<style name="MyStyle.Switch" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font_family</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/my_font_family</item>
</style>
```

still doesn't work though

Answer (score 1):

XML settings is not working, therefore I use following code:

```
someSwitch.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.roboto));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
```

replace into this

```
parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch"
```

Comment: it did not work, unfortunately, and instead hid the thumb and it's slider

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
public class CustomSwitchCompact extends SwitchCompat {

    public CustomSwitchCompact(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomSwitchCompact(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomSwitchCompact(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface myFonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Roboto_Bold.ttf");
            setTypeface(myFonts);
        }
    }
}
```

**XML file**

```
<com.test.CustomSwitchCompact
        android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:checked="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="SwitchCompat"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        app:showText="true" />
```

Another way to achieve SwitchCompact with custom font

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adamSwitch"
        android:textColor="@color/top_color"
        android:textAppearance="@color/top_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:showText="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/my_font_family"
        app:theme="@style/Custom.Widget.SwitchCompat"
        app:switchPadding="5dp"
        />
```

in style.xml

```
<style name="Custom.Widget.SwitchCompat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch" >
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue</item>  
            <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
            <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font_family</item>
             <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_primary_text</item>
      </style>
```

Comment: the custom class will work (with some minor changes to use the new font family xml, **ResourceCompat.getFont()**), I already have something like this but this is my last option as of the moment... the custom style via _app:theme_ does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: I see this problem as well using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.  I am applying a style that includes a font family as well as making the text all caps.  I see that the capitalization part of the style has been applied correctly to the SwitchCompat, but not the font.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works for me is `setSwitchTypeface`, **not** `setTypeface`:

```java
    my_switch.setSwitchTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.my_font))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `android:textAppearance` instead of `android:switchTextAppearance` and custom font works now. Also my switch style have `Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch` as parent